# Get distinct values for all columns for all tables from specific schema

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.5

I would like to get all distinct values for all columns in each table of a specific schema.

First, I summarised all my tables/columns in a new_table (myschema.dico)

```
  CREATE TABLE myschema.dico AS (
    WITH tables AS (
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'myschema' and table_type ='BASE TABLE' and table_name LIKE 'XXX' --criterias if needed
        ORDER BY table_name
                    )
    SELECT tables.table_name, 
    column_name, 
    concat(tables.table_name,'.',column_name) AS address, 
    concat ('myschema.',tables.table_name) AS home
    FROM information_schema.columns
    RIGHT JOIN tables ON tables.table_name = columns.table_name
    ORDER BY 1,2
    ;
```

Then, added a new column to update my distinct values

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.dico ADD COLUMN dico TEXT;
```

myschema.dico table looks like this:

| table_name | column_name | address | home | dico |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table1 | one | table1.one | myschema.table1 |  |
| table1 | two | table1.two | myschema.table1 |  |
| table1 | three | table1.three | myschema.table1 |  |
| table2 | aaa | table2.aaa | myschema.table2 |  |
| table2 | bbb | table2.bbb | myschema.table2 |  |

Then I tried to create a function to update all my 'dico' column's values with all distinct values :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dico_columns() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE

  cur_table CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT *
    FROM myschema.dico
    FOR UPDATE;
 cur_table_row RECORD ;
 
  cur_dico2 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT *
    FROM myschema.dico
    FOR UPDATE;
 cur_dico2_row RECORD ;
 
BEGIN

    OPEN cur_table;
    FETCH cur_table INTO cur_table_row;
    LOOP 
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        OPEN cur_dico2;
        FETCH cur_dico2 INTO cur_dico2_row;
        LOOP
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            
            IF cur_table_row.home IS NOT NULL 
            THEN  UPDATE myschema.dico 
                  SET dico= ( 
                              SELECT json_build_object(colname, array_agg(DISTINCT val))
                              FROM cur_table_row.home --refers to myschema.table 
                              CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(row_to_json(cur_table_row.table_name)) AS j(colname,val) --table_name = table
                              WHERE colname=cur_table_row.column_name --refers to table.column
                              GROUP BY colname)
                   WHERE CURRENT OF cur_dico2;

            END IF;
            FETCH cur_dico2 INTO cur_dico2_row;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur_dico2;
        FETCH cur_table INTO cur_table_row;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_table;
    
END ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
SELECT dico_columns();
```

Unfortunately it seems not possible to use 'FROM cursor_row.value'.
I tried many things but I'm not familiar with functions.

Do you have a better idea ?

Currently on postgres 9.5.

Comment: you need to use https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ecpg-dynamic.html also your version is very very old.

Comment: Thanks nbk, could you give a hand please ? I'm struggling to insert sql dynamic with cursor. Didn't find a lot of examples online

Comment: you see chapter 33.5.3. the command string is like yours, where you have table_row.home you need to concat text like SELECT json_build_object  with the variables.  see if that helps you further. when not post here and i will see if i can get some thing to work

Comment: I'm trying to apply your advices without success.
Honestly, I barely understand what I'm currently trying to do with json_build_object and inserting the 33.5.3 section. More help would be required to clear my mind, if that's not too much asking.

Comment: If I try to declare any 'EXEC SQL...' statements within my function, it shows an error while the documentation says : '. Depending on the particular statement, they can appear at the global level or within a function.' ..I'm not getting right something ..

Comment: you hole sELeCT is a mess. take https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=80d4d3438d34f863673849e9d2c7f642 and try you Select  that oruces dico, so that it runs with alle necessary tables. i can't make heads or tales form that what you wrote. When you have a text that wil produce your row entry i will se if i can get it with cursors to work

Comment: would it help ? [link] (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c136a8dc4a09fa15b938ec64e7395651)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs some refinement, but to show you how to get it started

but basucally make a update a simple update with public.Selecttext and you achieve the same, without loop

> ```
> CREATE TABLE dico
>     ("table_name" varchar(6), "column_name" varchar(5), "address" varchar(12), "home" varchar(15), "dico" TEXT)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO dico
>     ("table_name", "column_name", "address", "home", "dico")
> VALUES
>     ('table1', 'one', 'table1.one', 'myschema.table1', ''),
>     ('table1', 'two', 'table1.two', 'myschema.table1', ''),
>     ('table1', 'three', 'table1.three', 'myschema.table1', ''),
>     ('table2', 'aaa', 'table2.aaa', 'myschema.table2', ''),
>     ('table2', 'bbb', 'table2.bbb', 'myschema.table2', '')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     ("one" varchar(6), "two" varchar(5), "three" varchar(12))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     ("one", "two", "three")
> VALUES
>     ('a', 'd', 'f'),
>     ('b', 'd', 'h'),
>     ('a', 'd', 'g'),
>     ('c', 'e', 'f'),
>     ('a', 'e', 'g')
> ;
>
> CREATE TABLE table2
>     ("aaa" varchar(6), "bbb" varchar(5))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table2
>     ("aaa", "bbb")
> VALUES
>     ('aa', 'dd'),
>     ('bbb', 'd'),
>     ('aaa', 'd'),
>     ('ab', 'ee'),
>     ('aba', 'ee')
> ;
> ```

> 

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.Selecttext(tablen text, coln text)
> RETURNS SETOF RECORD
> LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
> AS $BODY$
> BEGIN 
>     RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT textcol::TEXT FROM (SELECT json_build_object(colname, array_agg(DISTINCT val)) AS textcol FROM '
>     ||$1||E'  CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(row_to_json( '
>     ||$1||E' )) AS j(colname,val) WHERE colname =  \''
>     ||$2||E'\' GROUP BY colname) t2';
> END 
> $BODY$;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dico_columns() RETURNS void AS $$
> DECLARE
>
>   cur_table CURSOR FOR 
>     SELECT "table_name", "column_name", "address", "home", "dico"
>     FROM dico
>     ;
>    _tabl text;
>    _coln text;
>    _address text;
>    _home text;
>    _dico text;
>  
>
> BEGIN
>
>     OPEN cur_table;
>     LOOP
>     FETCH cur_table INTO _tabl,_coln,_address,_home,_dico;
>      
>         EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
>
>   IF _home IS NOT NULL  THEN
>                UPDATE dico 
>                 SET dico= (sELECT textcol FROM  Selecttext(_tabl,_coln) AS t(textcol TEXT)) 
>                 WHERE "table_name" = _tabl AND "column_name"  = _coln
>                 AND "home"  = _home;
>                    
>   END IF;
>
>     END LOOP;
>     CLOSE cur_table;
>     
> END ;
>
> $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
>     
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT dico_columns()
> ```
>
> ```
> | dico_columns |
> | :----------- |
> |              |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT json_build_object(colname, array_agg(DISTINCT val)) AS textcol
> FROM table1
> CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(row_to_json(table1)) AS j(colname,val) 
> WHERE colname='one' 
> GROUP BY colname
> ```
>
> ```
> | textcol                 |
> | :---------------------- |
> | {"one" : ["a","b","c"]} |
> ```

> ```
> sELECT textcol FROM  Selecttext('table1','one') AS t(textcol TEXT)
> ```
>
> ```
> | textcol                 |
> | :---------------------- |
> | {"one" : ["a","b","c"]} |
> ```

> ```
> sELECT textcol FROM  Selecttext('table1','two') AS t(textcol TEXT)
> ```
>
> ```
> | textcol             |
> | :------------------ |
> | {"two" : ["d","e"]} |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * frOM dico
> ```
>
> ```
> table_name | column_name | address      | home            | dico                                   
> :--------- | :---------- | :----------- | :-------------- | :--------------------------------------
> table1     | one         | table1.one   | myschema.table1 | {"one" : ["a","b","c"]}                
> table1     | two         | table1.two   | myschema.table1 | {"two" : ["d","e"]}                    
> table1     | three       | table1.three | myschema.table1 | {"three" : ["f","g","h"]}              
> table2     | aaa         | table2.aaa   | myschema.table2 | {"aaa" : ["aa","aaa","ab","aba","bbb"]}
> table2     | bbb         | table2.bbb   | myschema.table2 | {"bbb" : ["d","dd","ee"]}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=93d25c9aacc2a5505990b866236709e8)*

Comment: I'm looking forward to discuss this code with you to understand and learn, if you don't mind. Don't know how to do it through this website though

Comment: we can set up a chat or at least i can. but please [accept my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)  the thing is basically simle, you got Selecttext which creates the query you wanted, so you get your json for every row in you table. this is basically only a string concatination which then is run.

Answer (score 0):

excellent job !

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.Selecttext(tablen text, coln text, homen text)
    RETURNS SETOF RECORD
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $BODY$
    BEGIN 
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT textcol::TEXT FROM (SELECT json_build_object(colname, array_agg(DISTINCT val)) AS textcol FROM '
        ||$3||E'  CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(row_to_json( '
        ||$1||E' )) AS j(colname,val) WHERE colname =  \''
        ||$2||E'\' GROUP BY colname) t2';
    END 
    $BODY$;
```

I added the parameter home, as it was not working in a schema <>public, now it works on my side.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dico_columns() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE

  cur_table CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT "table_name", "column_name", "address", "home", "dico"
    FROM myschema.dico
    ;
   _tabl text;
   _coln text;
   _address text;
   _home text;
   _dico text;
 

BEGIN

    OPEN cur_table;
    LOOP
    FETCH cur_table INTO _tabl,_coln,_address,_home,_dico;
     
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

  IF _home IS NOT NULL  THEN
               UPDATE myschema.dico 
                SET dico= (sELECT textcol FROM  Selecttext(_tabl,_coln, _home) AS t(textcol TEXT)) 
                WHERE "table_name" = _tabl AND "column_name"  = _coln
                AND "home"  = _home;
                   
  END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_table;
    
END ;
```